# Young Priests' Finger Noise on Yom Kippur

Tags: kohen-priest, beis-hamikdash, yom-kippur

In Mishnah Yuma [1:7](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%90_%D7%90_%D7%96),

> ביקש להתנמנם, פרחי כהונה מכין לפניו באצבע צרידה
>
> If he [the Cohen Gadol] sought to doze, the sprouting youths of the
>   priesthood would strike before him with a צרידה finger.

[left צרידה untranslated because not sure what it means]

It seems from Kehati's explanation that this is the familiar action of snapping one's fingers, done using the middle finger, thumb, and palm. But Bartenura seems to say it involves the first finger: how would that work--how would a sound be made?

Comment: It's possible that the snapping involves three fingers - the middle, first, and thumb...

Comment: Like the snap Ali G makes

Comment: @ClintEastwood, could you describe what that snap is?

Comment: the word is "strike". Maybe they poked him?

Comment: @DanF, it says they strike לפניו (before him), not they strike אותו (him). So, doesn't seem like it involves contact with him.

Comment: @paquda I'd upvote this comment but not sure you're intending to quote Ali G (with his accent) :)

Comment: Try it. You can snap using your index finger and thumb. It feels more natural to use your middle finger and thumb, sure, but it’s still possible.

Answer (score 2):

I had a Persian classmate in elementary school who would snap using his index finger. There  was a special way to hold both his hands and the noise was much louder than our snapping done with the thumb and middle finger on one hand.
I found some how to videos on YouTube. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xvWJg3FBWzQ) guy is having lots of fun. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cf5L7i0C8RA) lady does a little better getting across how loud it could be, but with the compression on YouTube videos, you'll never really get the full experience.

Apparently it's a very common middle eastern move. The words of Bartenura, and Rashi who he seems based off, could be read creatively as describing this technique. Considering their explanations seem based on a tradition of a practice neither one of them saw, I don't think that is such a stretch to assume.

Answer (score 0):

Rash"i on [Gemarah Yoma 19b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=19b&format=pdf) says that this noise is done by merging the index finger with the thumb and hitting the two against one's palm.

I tried it, and to me, this noise wouldn't wake me up, but, then again, I have arthritis :-)

Comment: Is that the opposite palm, or the palm of the same hand? I am finding the latter to be impossible.

Comment: @Chaim I don't mean to sound "trivial", but how could you physically do this move on the same hand?

Comment: @DanF, "... _this noise wouldn't wake me up_ ...". I think the idea is to snap the High Priest out of his drowsiness, before he is able to fall asleep ( _Bikesh le-Hitnamnem_, 'sought sleep', as opposed to _Hitnamnem_, 'fell asleep, slept', though I personally wouldn't translate _Nimnum_ as 'sleep'). Once he's actually fallen asleep, and needs waking up, the battle is lost. Also, I'd assume that, as it was in the High Priest's interest to remain awake, he would be more responsive to the weaker noise made.

Comment: @DanF precisely the issue I'm running into. Perhaps some Kohanim were double-jointed. (I'm being facetious.)

Comment: @TamirEvan,  regarding 'nimnum' what would be a better word? maybe 'doze'?

Comment: @Chaim "Perhaps some Kohanim were double-jointed." I doubt it. Wouldn't that be considered a *mum*?

Comment: @paquda Yes, something like that. The way I understand the passage: when the _Pirchei Kehunah_ saw the High Priest was about to doze off, they'd strike before him with an _'Etzba Tzeredah_ to snap him out of it. When I originally posted my comment, I was thinking along the lines of 'nap' or 'snooze', but now they seem a little colloquial to me, and 'doze [off]' does seem better.

Comment: @TamirEvan The Art Scroll Yom Kippur Machzor (Ashkenaz) translates the word as "doze".

Answer (score 0):

I learned that it was the same gesture made by the angel when a baby is born, to make him forget his Torah. It's called a fillip in English. It's like a flick of the fingers.

Comment: I don't think it's quite that. See my answer with a reference to Rash"i. As I understand it, it involved hitting the palm of your other hand.

Comment: @DanF There may be different traditions regarding this....